# How to find out what prevents a HTML5 video element from allowing me to change the playback rate via Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html5-video

On most videos I can do `video.playbackRate=1.5` and it works fine. However, I recently came across one that looks like it doesn't allow it (e.g. Amazon Prime videos). I can see it's set to 1.5 but within a fraction of a seconds it goes back to 1. Was able to see this by reading back video.playbackRate.

It looks that there is a listener for the ratechange event, or that some kind of attribute somewhere prevents such interaction (the `<video>` element itself has only `src,height,width` attributes).

I can confirm that `video.onratechange=null` so presumably there are listeners added using `video.addEventListener()`. However, `getEventListeners(video)` returns only `{seeked: Array(1), encrypted: Array(1)}` so there doesn't seem to be any event listener on `ratechange`

How can I find out what is preventing me to change playbackRate (or what is setting back to 1)? Are there other listeners I can dig up using other means? Any pointers will be gratefully received.

Comment: They can change playback rate every millisecond. You can search through source code for a line that changes that and see what triggers it

Comment: @Konrad I had already tried adding a listener for ratechange to print to console, and the listener was never called ... it's weird. Something is setting the rate back to 1.0 though